# Why users are not displayed from the database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I can't get a list of users from the database.I am assuming userService.allUsers () = null. But why? I have no idea. Since there are users in the database. Please tell me what is wrong with my code? It does not give me any errors in the logs.
AdminController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/forAdmin")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/forAdmin")
public String userList(Model model) {

    Iterable<User> allUser = userService.allUsers();

    if(allUser != null){
        model.addAttribute("allUsers", allUser);
    } else {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    return "forAdmin";
}
```

Class UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Autowired
public UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
public RoleRepository roleRepository;
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь не найден");
    }
    return user;
}

public User findUserById(Long userId) {
    Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
    return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
}

public List<User> allUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public boolean saveUser(User user) {
    User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (userFromDB != null) {
        return false;
    }

    user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteUser(Long userId) {
    if (userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

ForAdmin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c=""
  xmlns:el="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>forAdmin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2> Admin Page</h2>
  <a th:href="@{/index}">Main</a>

  <div th:each= "el :${allUsers}">
     <p th:text="${el.id}" />
     <p th:text="${el.username}" />
  </div>

</body>
</html>

Interface UserRepository

@Component
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I do not even understand why nothing is written to me in the logs, as if the data does not reach thymeleaf.Tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: you shouldnt be assuming you should have used your debugger and told us exactly if it is null or not... Also please show your Repository class.

Comment: added repository.So the fact is that in the debugger and does not write any errors.Shows that the localhost is working fine, the base has pulled up, there are no errors there ...

Comment: U don’t need @Component for the repository. Also that is not what I meant - set a breakpoint at findAll and see if it returns null or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i might already know what your problem is - you have defined the endpoint `forAdmin` twice: once at class level and once again with `@GetMapping`. The resulting endpoint is `localhost/forAdmin/forAdmin` and of course if you have been using `localhost/forAdmin` the endpoint wouldn’t get loaded